# Kotlin get value for response json list

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit

I am new to Kotlin.
I trying to make an API call with retrofit.

when making the call to the api it responds to me:

```
{
"recordsets": [
    [
        {
            "UsuarioId": 2101,
            "Nombre": "Jose Perez",
            "UsuarioDominio": "jose.perez",            
            "Correo": "jose.p@correo.com.mx"
        }
    ]
],
"recordset": [
     {
            "UsuarioId": 2101,
            "Nombre": "Jose Perez",
            "UsuarioDominio": "jose.perez",            
            "Correo": "jose.p@correo.com.mx"
        }
],
"output": {},
"rowsAffected": [],
"returnValue": 0,}
```

I need get value  "UsuarioId": 2101 and "Correo": "jose.p@correo.com.mx"

Model:

```
    data class ResponseLogin(
    val recordsets: List<List<Recordset2>>)


data class Recordset2(
    val Activo: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("correo")  val Correo: String,
    val IdDepartamento: Int,
    val IdEmpleado: Int,
    val IdEmpresa: Any,
    val IdPlaza: Int,
    val IdPuesto: Int,
    val Nombre: String,
    val Plaza: String,
    val UsuarioDominio: String,
    val UsuarioId: Int)
```

Code MainActivity

```
  retrofit.requestLogin(obj).enqueue(
                object: Callback<ResponseLogin>{
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<ResponseLogin>,
                        response: Response<ResponseLogin>
                    ) {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,response.message().Correo.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                          }
```

I need get value  "UsuarioId": 2101 and "Correo": "jose.p@correo.com.mx"

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the value(s) from the response, you will need to traverse through the response data.

```
retrofit.requestLogin(obj).enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseLogin> {
    override fun onResponse(
        call: Call<ResponseLogin>,
        response: Response<ResponseLogin>
    ) {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val recordsets = response.body()?.recordsets
            recordsets?.forEach { usuarioList ->
                usuarioList.forEach { usuario ->
                    val usuarioId = usuario.UsuarioId
                    val correo = usuario.Correo

                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "Usuario Id: $usuarioId, Correo: $correo",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```